# "Pause queue" using sidekiq pro is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using "Sidekiq Pro" and I have implemented "Pause Queue" functionality by using Sidekiq Pro API. The code is:

```
q = Sidekiq::Queue.new(params[:queue_name])
q.pause!
```

In sidekiq Pro Web UI Its showing me the queue is paused. But when I am adding job, the paused queue is processing a job. I don't want the paused queue process job. Is there any settings I need to add to implement "pause queue"  feature and paused queue should not process jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes

1. The Sidekiq process must be using reliable fetch or it will not pause.
2. It can take up to 10 seconds for pause! and unpause! to take effect.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Pro-API#pausing-queues

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add reliable fetch settings in the initializer file.

Comment: I have added  `Sidekiq::Client.reliable_push! unless Rails.env.test?` line and in server configure block I have added  `config.reliable_fetch!`